# Compilation Help on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: compiling, c

I have recently gotten into programming this is a small C code I started on.

I am using Ubuntu 13.10.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

    puts("Hello world.");

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I try to compile it using

```
gcc exl.c -o exl1
cc exl.c -o exl1
```

or anything like that i just keep getting

```
gcc: error: exl.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: No input files
compilation terminated.
```

I have no Idea what to do any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I have already done

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get update build-essential
sudo apt-get upgrade build-essential
```

Comment: Well, the error is about a non-existing `exl.c` file. Are you sure you saved the code to the contents of a file with that exact name in the current working directory or changing to the full path? This is really a 'simple' file location issue, rather than a compilation error.

Comment: Do let us know when you compile it successfully.

Comment: I fixed it, all it required was for me to make a directory for the file and run the terminal in the file, thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run gcc in a directory where your C code is stored, so first use:

```
cd /home/your-user-name/path-to-program-dir
```

and then run gcc. To make sure that you have to C file in same directory use

```
ls *.c
```

which will show you all the C files in current directory. If you are not sure in which directory your code is stored then you may want to use

```
find
```

Comment: Thanks, I recently found the issue was that I wasn't running the terminal in the directory and I didn't have a directory made. Thank you again for helping fix this situation.

Answer (score -1):

If you use gedit then after saving c file use ctrl-M. It will open terminal in your program directory.